# How to store loop output of each iteration to data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

Ok so I have a loop that works out the annualized / cumulative return of a stock price series.

I wish to do the same thing over many files. So made a loop to do so.

First some dummy data:

```
    # Create dummy data
    # Use lubridate to change timestamp to date format
    # Use dplyr to arrange by ascending order
    # Use fread from data.table to read .csv to data frame
    require(lubridate)
    require(data.table)
    require(dplyr)
    MSFT <- fread("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=6RSYX9BPXKZVXUS9&datatype=csv")
    MSFT$timestamp <- ymd(MSFT$timestamp)
    MSFT <- arrange(MSFT,timestamp)
    AAPL <- fread("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AAPL&outputsize=full&apikey=6RSYX9BPXKZVXUS9&datatype=csv")
    AAPL$timestamp <- ymd(AAPL$timestamp)
    AAPL <- arrange(AAPL,timestamp)
    NFLX <- fread("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=NFLX&outputsize=full&apikey=6RSYX9BPXKZVXUS9&datatype=csv")
    NFLX$timestamp <- ymd(NFLX$timestamp)
    NFLX <- arrange(NFLX,timestamp)
    TSLA <- fread("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TSLA&outputsize=full&apikey=6RSYX9BPXKZVXUS9&datatype=csv")
    TSLA$timestamp <- ymd(TSLA$timestamp)
    TSLA <- arrange(TSLA,timestamp)

    # Place data frames in a list
    df.list <- list(MSFT,AAPL,NFLX,TSLA)

# Specify file names
    file.names <- c("MSFT","AAPL","NFLX","TSLA")
```

Now that prepares the data.

Next I want to calculate the cumulative and annualized returns for each series. I place this in a function then call the function with a loop:

```
    # Create function for performing commands.
    genAnnualized = function(x){
      next.file <- data.frame(df.list[[1]],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      next.name <- paste0(file.names[i])
      new.df <- data.frame(next.file)

      # Calculate annualized return 
      # Make prices vector
      prices <- new.df[, "close", drop = FALSE]

      # Denote n the number of time periods:
      n <- nrow(prices)

      # Calculate close to close returns
      # lead in with rep,NA,1 to maintain length of vector comparible to data frame
      close_ret <- c(rep(NA, 1),(prices[2:n, 1] - prices[1:(n-1), 1])/prices[1:(n-1), 1])
      close_ret[1] <- 0

      # Compute continuously  returns (log returns)
      close_ccret <- log(prices[2:n, 1]) - log(prices[1:(n-1), 1])

      # Compute gross returns
      close_gret <- 1 + close_ret   # use close to close ret

      # Compute future values
      close_fv <- cumprod(close_gret)

      # Obtain first and last values
      ret.last <- tail(close_fv, n=1)
      ret.first <- head(close_fv, n=1)
      cum.ret <- (ret.last-ret.first)/ret.first

      # Get First And Last row to calculate time between
      ret.first.row <- head(new.df$timestamp, n=1)
      ret.last.row <- tail(new.df$timestamp, n=1)

     # Time diff 
     #trading.years.between <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(ret.last.row), as.Date(ret.first.row), unit="weeks"))/52.25

      # Find time diff
      ret.time <- ret.last.row - ret.first.row
      ret.trading.years.between <- ret.time/365   #252 trading days or 365 
      ret.trading.years.between <- as.numeric(ret.trading.years.between, units="days")   # Extract numerical value from time difference 'Time difference of 2837.208 days'
      # Annualized return
      # (1 + % diff of final) / (last balance to the power of 1/time first and last balance) -1
      ret.annual.return <- (1+cum.ret) ^ (1/ret.trading.years.between) -1

      ########## Store annualized and cumulative return in data frame for each iteration #########
      # Store file name as a row name :: next.name variable
      # Store final annualized return :: cret.annual.return
      # Store final cumulative return :: cum.ret
      output.df <- cbind(cum.ret,ret.annual.return)
      rownames(output.df) <- next.name

##################################################################

      # Sanity check, use PerformanceAnalytics for annualized return
      # TTR for returns
      # Calculate Close-to-Close returns
      require(TTR)
      require(PerformanceAnalytics)
      new.df$clret <- ROC(new.df$close, type = c("discrete"))
      new.df$clret[1] <- 0
      # Make time series object of returns and date
      require(xts)
      xts1 = xts(new.df$clret, order.by=as.Date(new.df$timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y")) 
      Return.annualized(xts1)
      Return.cumulative(xts1, geometric=TRUE)
    }
```

And call the function to loop through each data frame in the data frame list:

```
for (i in 1:length(df.list)){
  tryCatch({
    genAnnualized(df.list[[i]])
  }, error = function(e) { print(paste("i =", i, "failed:")) })
}
```

This should make a re producible example.

On each iteration, I wish to store the cumulative and annualized return of each series as with the name of the data set (so its identifiable later). 
I am attempting this with the below within my function:

```
  output.df <- cbind(cum.ret,ret.annual.return)
  rownames(output.df) <- next.name
```

I am specifying the names with:

```
file.names <- c("MSFT","AAPL","NFLX","TSLA")
```

and then in the function calling it:

```
next.name <- paste0(file.names[i])
```

I was hoping to paste the file name so I can tag my final output in the data frame.

I think might need to rep the name twice when naming each row or column name. So that it tags the cumulative return and also the annualized return.

I think have the general idea but have been wrestling with this for a few weeks so looking for some assistance.

Essentially with the output data frame I can then organise into quartiles etc etc for further analysis

Comment: I always handle these situations by assigning values to a dataframe or list within the loop i.e alist[]<-genAnnualized(df.list[[i]]

Comment: You have a hard-coded `df.list[[1]]` in the first line of your function - that doesn't seem right. Also your function should `return()` something - right now it is returning `Return.cumulative(xts1, geometric=TRUE)`, but `Return.annualized(xts1)` is computed but not used or returned.

Comment: I would recommend writing your function so it takes, say, a data frame  and a name as arguments, and operates on them with no "awareness" that it's inside a loop - no references to `i` or `df.list` inside the function. Then you can, as CCurtis suggests, do something like `results = list(); for (i in seq_along(df_list)) results[[i]] = genAnnualized(dat = df.list[[i]], name = file.names[i])`

Comment: Yes I changed to df.list[[i]] that does the job. Read up on return() and see how it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My simplest solution was to `rbind` a dataframe for each `file.names` evaluation, and name this row the same name of the corresponding file.
 I've deleted comments for clarity (and put some of mine).

```
'genAnnualized' = function(df_list) {

  next.file <- data.frame(df_list, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # Put the parameter of the function here
  next.name <- paste0(file.names[i])
  new.df <- data.frame(next.file)

  prices <- new.df[, "close", drop = FALSE]
  n <- nrow(prices)

  close_ret <- c(rep(NA, 1),(prices[2:n, 1] - prices[1:(n-1), 1])/prices[1:(n-1), 1])
  close_ret[1] <- 0
  close_ccret <- log(prices[2:n, 1]) - log(prices[1:(n-1), 1])
  close_gret <- 1 + close_ret  
  close_fv <- cumprod(close_gret)
  ret.last <- tail(close_fv, n=1)
  ret.first <- head(close_fv, n=1)
  cum.ret <- (ret.last-ret.first)/ret.first
  ret.first.row <- head(new.df$timestamp, n=1)
  ret.last.row <- tail(new.df$timestamp, n=1)

  ret.time <- ret.last.row - ret.first.row
  ret.trading.years.between <- ret.time/365  
  ret.trading.years.between <- as.numeric(ret.trading.years.between, units="days")  

  ret.annual.return <- (1+cum.ret) ^ (1/ret.trading.years.between) -1

  output.df <- cbind(cum.ret,ret.annual.return)
  rownames(output.df) <- next.name

  ##################################################################

  new.df$clret <- TTR::ROC(new.df$close, type = c("discrete"))
  new.df$clret[1] <- 0
  xts1 = xts::xts(new.df$clret, order.by=as.Date(new.df$timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y")) 

  # Create the output of the function : a named data.frame 
  out_df <- data.frame("Annualized Return" = PerformanceAnalytics::Return.annualized(xts1),
                       "Cumulative Return" = PerformanceAnalytics::Return.cumulative(xts1, geometric=TRUE))
  return(out_df)
}

# Initialize the output dataframe to which we will rowbind the results
cum_ret <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(df.list)){
    temp <- genAnnualized(df.list[[i]] )
    rownames(temp) <- file.names[i]
    cum_ret <- rbind.data.frame(cum_ret, temp)
}
```

This gives a data frame with number of named rows equal to the number of 
files in `df.list` and 2 columns for the annualized and cumulative returns.

```
> cum_ret
     Annualized.Return Cumulative.Return
MSFT       -0.02279597        -0.3361359
AAPL        0.02039616         0.4314812
NFLX        0.17454862        10.8991045
TSLA        0.44666765        13.8233571
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how this is structured now. Essentially I was thinking I needed to store every iteration in the same df inside the function and keep building it in there. However, I see we are only placing the final result of that iteration, then using return(). What does return(df) do? And how does that interact with the loop calling the function? Does return simple disregard everything else in the function, return our output which is then the only thing grabbed when we call the function in the loop?